# ChangeDisplaySettings() fails when try to acess remoting

Tags: c#

When trying to Rotate Desktop, running the code in a Remote Desktop, I've got the exception:

> Error trying to GetActiveDisplays() : QueryDisplayConfig() failed. Status: InvalidParameter;

Running it in local works fine!

**It is not possible to do in Remote Desktop?**

The code is:

```
var pathInfoArray = new DisplayConfigPathInfo[numPathArrayElements];
var modeInfoArray = new DisplayConfigModeInfo[numModeInfoArrayElements];

// topology ID only valid with QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT
var queryDisplayStatus = pathType == QueryDisplayFlags.DatabaseCurrent ?
CCDWrapper.QueryDisplayConfig(
pathType,
ref numPathArrayElements, pathInfoArray,
ref numModeInfoArrayElements, modeInfoArray, out topologyId) :

CCDWrapper.QueryDisplayConfig(
pathType,
ref numPathArrayElements, pathInfoArray,
ref numModeInfoArrayElements, modeInfoArray);
```

Running this on remote desktops `queryDisplayStatus` returns with `InvalidParameter`.

Comment: `Error Code and Description` for the following 
`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
The combination of parameters and flags that are specified is invalid.` so can you show the exact method and call that you are using in your local environment that's working..?

Comment: not sure if this will help but what the heck http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56548/

Comment: Just updated with the code

Comment: ok looking at the code if it works on your local and not on the remote I am wondering what `var pathInfoArray` value is when you debug it locally I bet there is an issue with file paths not being the same locally vs remotely

Comment: look at this example I do not see a QueryOnlyActivePaths in your example maybe this could be what's also missing .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087613/how-do-i-set-the-monitor-orientation-in-windows-7