# Change Display Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multiple-monitors

-Background-

I Currently have 4 Monitors, 3 normal Full HD ones and one 4k TV for gaming.
Now i want to create a new User Account which should automatically setup everything when it starts.
So i want to disable the normal 3 monitors and leave only the TV as main desktop and start steam in Big-Picture Mode.
I now created a program which starts when the user logs in and starts Steam correctly.

-My Problem-

I can´t find anything on how to change the Display-configuration, only how to change the resolution or stuff like that, but how can i disable a Monitor?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233411/how-do-i-enable-a-second-monitor-in-c

Comment: You may want to look here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26343745/86860 (note, the GitHub page moved to here it seems: https://github.com/Jaykul/MultiMonitorHelper)

Comment: @Nate it isn't the original repository. Christ, the author of multimonitorhelper, has closed the project.